# Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory using babel CLI

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm struggling to get my jsx files compiled using babel + presets. My project structure is a bit non-standard as js/jsx files are placed in a sibling directory of the config/build files:

```
.
├── frontend_config
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── babel-cli
│   │   ├── babel-core
|   |   | ...
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
├── jsx
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── Bar.jsx
...
```

I've narrowed down the issue to the minimal by trying to run babel from the terminal, inside the `frontend_config` directory I run:

```
npx babel ../jsx/foo/Bar.jsx --presets=env,react
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "../jsx/foo"
```

I've installed both `babel-preset-env` and `babel-preset-react` but I don't know how to tell babel where are they placed. I've also tried using a `.babelrc`file but the behavior is the same.

My setup is:

```
$ npx babel --version
6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.0)
$ node --version
v8.9.4
```

Answer (score 2):

You have installed babel dependencies like cli, presets, plugins in frontend_config folder and you're transpiling JSX files which are not placed in same root babel installed. That is why, it shows like 
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

do like below in your webpack/grunt/.babelrc  :

```
use absolute paths
```

or use require like below :

```
var babelenv = require('babel-preset-env');
var babelreact = require('babel-preset-react');
var babelamd = require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd');
```

and 
`presets: [ babelenv, babelreact],plugins : [ babelamd ]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: `../frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015` and `./frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-react` are not absolute paths but relative. The solution is actually to use absolute paths.

Comment: that us what I have suggested to use absolute paths , is my answer solved your problem or not ?

Comment: the paths in your example are relative. If you fix them I can accept the answer

Comment: mentioned short hand path '../frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015' because you only know the full path of your project ..I just guided you to do like that, anyhow the final answer is using absolute paths or require

Answer (score 1):

run `npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev`

More info @ https://babeljs.io/

Comment: that's for babel 7

Comment: he can easily update babel since he's using node >= 8

Comment: babel 6 and 7 are very different. it's not just a simple `npm install`

Comment: also, he says he already has `babel-preset-env` installed, so this isn't the right answer either way

Comment: i understand that, and you're right that they're different, but since it's still a boilerplate, he can delete the package.json altogether and startover with the latest versions of everything.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue, the solution when using Babel 6 and placing `node_modules` in a different directory than the project root is to use **absolute paths**. Hence the babel call would look like:

```
npx babel ../jsx/foo/Bar.jsx --presets /Users/foo/bar/frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-env/,/Users/foo/bar/frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-react/
```

Credit to the answer goes to [loganfsmyth](https://github.com/loganfsmyth)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put this in your .babelrc file if you like

```
{
  "presets" : [ "/Users/foo/bar/frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-env" ]
}
```

Comment: Well technically I think you would need this given your example


    {
      "presets" : [ "/Users/foo/bar/frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-env/","/Users/foo/bar/frontend_config/node_modules/babel-preset-react/ "]  
}